# Touch Sensitivity

Tags: touchscreen

Is it possible to change the touch sensitivity of the android? Too often, I find myself working too hard to tap lightly so as not to make accidental selections.

I'm using ICS on the galaxy nexus.

Answer (score 4):

No there is not a way to do this for android, unless root access allows this (which it may). To do something like this you would have to change the size of the capacitive recognition. The screen is not pressurized, but rather interacts with the electrical interference of the screen.

Tapping lightly won't do anything other than reduce the amount of your finger that touches the screen. I would recommend getting a capacitive stylus if you're having problems with this.

Here is a cheap solution for this:

[http://www.amazon.com/Capacitive-Cellphone-Motorola-BlackBerry-AMM0101US/dp/B0053NBLFW/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1340657015&sr=8-1&keywords=capacitive+stylus](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0053NBLFW)

Hope this helps!